# Using New/delete on CUDA

Tags: cuda

I heard that with new graphics cards (compatibility >= 2.0) I could use `new` and `delete` directly on a kernel.

1. If I use `new` on a kernel, will I allocate memory in "global memory"?
2. If I create an object with `new` into a GPU, is the object's lifetime the same as the kernel lifetime, or as the application lifetime?
3. I heard that that using `new` on a kernel is not convenient. Is that right? Why?

**UPDATED:** 
Could someone post a link to some documentation about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. right
2. as the application lifetime
3. new and malloc in kernel is very convenient, but its amount is limited.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you mean when you say that "its amount is limited"? What is its limit?

Comment: I mean one kernel can malloc a little size. please take a look at cudaDeviceGet/SetLimit function or programming guide.